# How can I change the font style of the bibliography? (Arial Narrow 10pt)

Tags: fonts, bibliographies, miktex, texmaker, arial

I'm new here and I don't know how it really works. I was searching a lot about how to solve my problem but I couldn't find any solution.

I'm currently doing my Master's thesis in LaTeX and I don't really expert at this. I have to do all my thesis in Arial's font 12pt except bibliography section, that it has to be Arial Narrow 10pt.

My code is this:

*For all the document (Arial):*

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{helvet} 
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
```

*For the bibliography:*

```
\bibliographystyle{vancouver}
{\footnotesize 
\bibliography{bibliografiaTFM}}
```

I pretend to change the font size like this, but **I don't know really know if it's 10 pt.**

However, **I'm not capable of change the font style (to Arial Narrow)**.

I'm using `Jabref` program to do the references and I don't have xelatex or lualatex (because I don't really know how to install it). I compile the document with PdfLaTeX and Bib(la)tex.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Is `Arial Narrow` a font that's installed on your system? Please also tell us more about your TeX installation (including its vintage) and which editor/front end you employ to edit and compile your tex file(s).

Comment: I don't think so. How can I see the TeX installation information and the editor? I'm a bit lost (as I said I'm new in this and I don't really know how it works. I started learning LaTeX with Youtube Tutorials...).

Comment: helvet is helvetica, not arial. Beside this you should be able to use the condensed font series, but how exactly depends on your latex version. Is it a new tex system?

Comment: What kind of computer do you use? Is there a TeX installation on your computer, or are you using an online service such as Overleaf? Suppose your main tex file is called `main.tex`. Can you search the directory that contains `main.tex` for a file called `main.log`? (Replace `main` with whatever the real filename is.) Assuming you can find the log file, please open it in a text editor and tell us what the first few lines say.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I know that helvet is helvetica and not exactly Arial, but I read in one post that it was more less the same. Therefore, I used that font.
As I said I don't have xelatex or lualatex, that I saw that it's neccesary if I want to use Arial font.

Comment: @Mico I use it in my computer. In main.log file puts this:

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (MiKTeX 20.6.29) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2020.7.3)  8 JUL 2020 19:28
entering extended mode
**./tfm.tex
(tfm.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-06-18>
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\size12.clo"
File: size12.clo 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)

Do you need more information?

Comment: Good news -- you have an up-to-date MikTeX distribution installed on your computer! Now: Are you absolutely sure that LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX were *not* installed when you uploaded and installed MikTeX? Which editor program do you use to compile your LaTeX files?

Comment: @Mico If I'm honest I don't really know if I have LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX installed. I supposed that it's not because I can't use the codes that I found in some of this posts. When I installed MikTeX distribution I installed the basic TeX/LaTeX system on Windows because I had problems to install the complete one.

The editor program that I use to compile is Texmaker, 5.04 version.

Comment: @Mico I have already seen that in Texmaker appears in Tools section that I have LuaLaTex and XeLaTeX. But I don't know how to use it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAICT, there are two separate issues that need to get resolved: (a) How to inform the front-end/editor that you wish to compile your document with LuaLaTeX (or XeLaTeX) rather than with pdfLaTeX; and (b) how to modify the tex file so that you can use the system fonts called `Arial` and `Arial Narrow`.

I can't help you with the first issue as I don't use TeXmaker. However, I trust you'll manage to figure it out.

On the second issue: First, you should no longer load the `inputenc` and `fontenc` packages; in their place, load the `fontspec` package (by issuing the command `\usepackage{fontspec}` instruction in the preamble. Next, issue the instructions

```
\setmainfont{Arial}
\setsansfont{Arial}
```

in the preamble. Obviously (I hope...), you should no longer run `\usepackage{helvet}` or `\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}`.

Lastly, right before issuing the instruction `\bibliography{...}` in the body of the preamble, issue the following two instructions:

```
\setmainfont{Arial Narrow}
\setsansfont{Arial Narrow}
```

(I wrote a new comment to show you the images. Someone told me that I have to delete it. So I did it. And I was wrong writing it here. So sorry).

Comment: I could compile with LuaLatex! I thought that it would be more difficult but it wasn't.
However, when I changed bibliography font, it changed me the title and the number page style too. Can I change that?

\newpage
\setmainfont{Arial Narrow}
\setsansfont{Arial Narrow}
\bibliographystyle{vancouver}
{\footnotesize 
\bibliography{bibliografiaTFM}}


In addition, I need to ask you one more thing. \footnotesize command is right to get the words with 10pt size? Or it produces me bigger font size than that?

Thanks very much for everything.

Comment: @Eva - Indeed, If the document's main font size (aka `\normalsize`) is 12pt, then `\footnotesize` works out to be 10pt. Running `\setmainfont` and `\setsansfont` should definitely not change title and page number styles. How different are the the "new" styles from the old ones?

Comment: I have \setmainfont and \setsansfont but it changes it.
They are too different.. I would like to show you a picture compare the two styles but I don't know if I can. I can't find any option to upload one.

Comment: I added the pictures comparing the two styles in a new comment. Can you check them? Thanks.
As I said, I wrote the commands that you gave me, but it changes me all section.

Comment: First one, is the "old" style. Second one, the "new".

Also I show you the number styles. It's seems not too different. But I care more about the font style of "references" section.


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/93HEq.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gaz43.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WndS2.png
  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSBDF.png

Comment: the code I used is this

\bibliographystyle{vancouver}
\setmainfont{Arial Narrow}
\setsansfont{Arial Narrow}
{\footnotesize
\bibliography{bibliografiaTFM}}

Comment: @Eva - The screenshot you posted suggests that the Bold font face of `Arial Narrow` isn't being loaded correctly by default. What happens if you replace `\setmainfont{Arial Narrow}` with `\setmainfont{Arial Narrow}[BoldFont={Arial Narrow Bold}]` and recompile the document?

Comment: If I replace with that new command, it changes "References" title to bold, but it continues being Arial Narrow and I want it Arial and bold. (I only wanted Arial Narrow style in cites). However, I tried some things and I could resolved the problem!
\bibliographystyle{vancouver}
\setmainfont{Arial Narrow}[BoldFont={Arial Bold}]
{\footnotesize 
\bibliography{bibliografiaTFM}}
\setmainfont{Arial} %this is for the rest (number page and appendix that I want them to be Arial and not Arial Narrow)
\setsansfont{Arial}

Finally I solved the entire problem of this post. Thanks very much!!!

Comment: @Eva - Glad you were able to work out all the issues. E.g., I wasn't aware of the facts that (a) an appendix would follow the bibliography and (b) whereas the references should be typeset in `Arial Narrow` the title itself should continue to be typeset in `Arial [Bold]`.